Is it appropriate to acknowledge your family or even mention them in articles or slideshows?
What if I believe the research we conducted is not only the work of my supervisors or colleagues but also nearly all my family and I would like to acknowledge them in my slideshow or articles writing something like (suppose, which is false, my name is Bernard Roy):

Bernard Roy and his family, coauthor1, coauthor2, etc.

Is that appropriate? I want to add “and his family” in my slideshows and articles because my uncle drove me towards my lab a lot, my grandparents were of strong support by always pushing forward to succeed my thesis and so on.
Of course, this would be with the agreement of all the coauthors.

Do you want to add it to the acknowledgment or to author list? Your example mentions yourself, this is strange to do in acknowledgement...

The author list is a list of people's names. "His family" is not a person's name. You also cannot write "Bernard Roy and his neighbor", even if your neighbor is an actual coauthor.

The place where this would not look strange is to thank them in the acknowledgements sections of your thesis.  Theses often include personal acknowledgements - journal articles etc rarely do.

I am surprised by the downvotes - this is clearly inappropriate, but it is on-topic.

@Petr, both ideally, only one of the two possibilities otherwise

Contrary to what some of the other answers say, you cannot acknowledge anyone you like in an article, at least with some publishers. For example, the American Physical Society specifies:

Acknowledgments may be used to

Recognize named individuals who contributed scientifically to the research of the paper
Cite the funding agencies that provided financial support for the work
[…]

[…]
Acknowledgments may not be used to

[…]
Thank those who contributed general encouragement (e.g., family, friends)
Thank those who provided services that were not directly part of the research
Include a dedication or a memorial


I consider adhering to this rule a good idea in general. Moreover I find it likely that publishers that have no written rules against it, may still ask you to remove acknowledgements not related to funding or scientific contributions to avoid opening that can of worms.
The reason for this is that drawing the line at non-scientific acknowledgements is a rather certain way to stay clear of anything problematic. You may consider the support from your family crucial, others may want to acknowledge some deity, spiritual leader, beloved dictator, etc. And before you know it, all people from some country feel compelled to acknowledge their dictator or state-mandated deity, lest they face severe retributions. And this is just one example of how this can quickly escalate.

Authorship is completely off the table, as it is reserved for creative scientific contributions to the work. There are far stronger contributions that do not qualify for authorship, such as having acquired the funding, providing funding, or owning the lab.

"others may want to acknowledge some deity": possibly relevant question on this site

"at least with some publishers" is the key statement here.

I always suspected those guys who acknowledged the assistance of "Dr. Pepper" in the preparation of their paper. They got away with it, though.

I fully agree that family or similar acknowledgements are not suitable for a scientific paper or a presentation. However, there is one spot where such acknowledgements are welcome and common, namely a PhD thesis. These frequently have a lengthly acknowlegment section which not only contains thanks for scientific support but also thanks for help from family, friends, deities or whoever else the author wants to include.

As an editor, I have never objected to, or even commented on, anything an author has included in their acknowledgements. I question what this could "quickly escalate" to? If you want to spend a sentence or two thanking family or a deceased mentor I see no problem with that. If the acknowledgements section gets too long, or includes problematic issues, I still have authority to require changes to bring it in line. But in hundreds of reviewed articles, this has never once come up.

I certainly think Kim Jong Un should appear in the acknowledgements of all meteorology papers.

In acknowledgements:

You can acknowledge whomever you like. (Edit: not always, see @Wrzlprmft's answer. But the principle holds if the journal's policies do not forbid it.)

You don't generally need your coauthors' permission to acknowledge anyone. (But this doesn't mean they wouldn't get annoyed or embarrassed if you make inappropriate choices of people to acknowledge.) Naturally if they do not share your desire to acknowledge someone, the acknowledgement would name you personally as the person acknowledging that person. (E.g.: "JKHA thanks his uncle for driving him to the lab, often on weekends and/or during inclement weather.")

In extreme situations, say if you decide to acknowledge certain universally despised historical figures, the above may not apply and your coauthors may reasonably insist that you remove the acknowledgement if you want their agreement to go ahead and publish the paper. (I don't think that ought to apply to the situation of acknowledging family members though.)

Acknowledging family members is highly uncommon in a scientific paper.

Acknowledging family members (especially for the particular reasons you cited) in the acknowledgements section of a paper or in a scientific talk may make you look silly or overly sentimental and may affect other people's perceptions of you, possibly not in a positive way. But as I said above, it is still your right to include such acknowledgements if you desire to.

In the acknowledgements section of a thesis, there is more leeway to write something sentimental than in a paper. Acknowledgements to family members are very common in theses, and no one will care if you add one.


In authorship lists:

It is not appropriate to assign coauthorship to family members if your reason for assigning them coauthorship is that they "drove you to your lab" or "pushed you to succeed" etc. Any coauthor, whether a family member or not, needs to have made an intellectual contribution to the work.

You absolutely need the agreement of your other coauthors to add anyone else as an additional coauthor.



I found the second bullet a bit misleading until I read the third one. Authorship implies that all authors have read and agree with all aspects of the paper - the very act of publishing implies that the other authors did, in fact, grant permission to include the acknowledgement. It's not generally possible to publish something without stating that all authors agreed with every aspect of it. That said, I cannot imagine a major disagreement about the vast majority of possible acknowledgements, so permission for acknowledgement is often safely assumed (but that doesn't mean it's not granted).

@NuclearHoagie I disagree. By your logic, if I publish a paper with coauthors then that implies my coauthors granted me “permission” to spell my name in a certain way. I mean, they had the option of vetoing the paper and demanding I change the way I spell my name, but didn’t, right? That’s obviously an absurd interpretation. The same goes for the acknowledgement. As long as the acknowledgement does not imply the coauthors expressing an opinion they don’t want to express, they cannot reasonably withhold their approval. (Maybe except for some extreme exceptions as I stated.)

@DanRomik If I saw a paper that acknowledged Hitler or some equivalent, that would absolutely reflect poorly on every single author in the byline, even if only one author wrote and put their name to that specific acknowledgement - every author is responsible for the entire content of the paper. I could see some authors not wanting to include acknowledgements of pets, or deities, or coffee, or other non-human entities as well - I don't agree that you should presume your coauthors will be fine with anything or anyone you might want to acknowledge, or that they have no say in the matter anyway.

@NuclearHoagie that was precisely the point of my third bullet.

I find it weird that, especially for someone who's a postdoc like OP, acknowledging the people that made your academic work possible thru logistics and emotional support is considered "silly" or "sentimental". As far as I understand, junior researchers are not well paid, so it is even more critical for them to receive the sort of support OP describes.

@ave postdocs also need to eat. Should they acknowledge the farmer who grows their food? The grocer who sells it to them? A lot of things in life are critical, but we don't write about them in acknowledgements sections, because they are not of interest to anyone reading our scientific papers. I am grateful to my mother for many things, but to assume that that's something people want to hear about when they read my papers would be, literally, sentimental.

@ave by the way, in my answer I wrote "overly sentimental" not "sentimental". Some level of sentimentality could still be considered appropriate. We are all humans, not robots, after all.

@DanRomik you pay for the groceries, and the grocer pays the farmer for the produce, so that's not an accurate comparison. And besides, acknowledgements is not there to be of interest to readers, is it? You may thank your grant, but this info is useless to readers. What if someone selflessly contributed to your research thru help that isn't towards the text of the work, but rather making it possible where otherwise it may not have been? Did they not help as much as a grant, possibly?

@ave I'm not convinced, sorry. An academic journal is a place to publish scientific knowledge, not personal stories from your life. But as I said, you're free to acknowledge whoever you want.

In the US in my experience, it's traditional in the thesis defense specifically to thank family, significant others, close friends, past advisors: those who had an influence on your development as a researcher as a whole person.
In other scientific talks, though, I would stick to acknowledging the people who had direct input to the work being discussed. Not doing so could appear to dilute the contributions of your coauthors. I would be especially sensitive to this when the people you are acknowledging are your juniors in the academic hierarchy. I'd also encourage spreading acknowledgements throughout a talk: these experiments were done by Alice, Bob suggested we do this analysis of the data, Charlie collected the data used in this figure, etc.
It's possible your field has a different set of expectations or standards. I would also consider an exception for special circumstances, for example in my field at the biggest annual conference it is traditional that some invited talks are effectively "career talks" where a senior scientist outlines all the influential work across their entire career. Like a thesis defense at an earlier career stage, that may be an appropriate time to reach back to early and life-long influences.

Generally, you can acknowledge whom you like, even if they only provide moral support for your work. In a slide presentation it is even less of a problem.
But, in publications, getting agreement from co-authors is appropriate as you suggest, and an occasional reviewer or editor might object. In that case you can deal with it then. Journals with contrary policies will publish the rules with author instructions. You will need to adhere to such rules, of course.
It might be better, however, to say a few words about why you are including family, especially if they haven't made direct contributions. Funding, moral support, etc. Don't make it long or distracting for readers.
In a slide show, you can make it the last slide, which you put up at the end of a talk as you ask for questions but don't actually discuss.

Generally, you can acknowledge whom you like – That’s not generally true. See my answer.
